# How to call original method that includes a call to a faked method?

Tags: .net, microsoft-fakes

I'm using MS Fakes.

Give the following class:

```
public class Person
{
    public void SaveQuotes()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Original DoSomething called.");
    }
}
```

and this test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        var sut = new ShimPerson();

        sut.DoSomething = () => { Console.WriteLine("Called from test"); };

        sut.Instance.SaveQuotes();
    }
}
```

When I run the test, the `sut.Instance.SaveQuotes()` method is basically skipped over, since that method has been shimmed. What I want is to execute the original `SaveQuotes()` method. So I tried this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        var sut = new ShimPerson();

        sut.DoSomething = () => { Console.WriteLine("Called from test"); };
        sut.SaveQuotes = () => { ShimsContext.ExecuteWithoutShims(() => sut.Instance.SaveQuotes()); };

        sut.Instance.SaveQuotes();
    }
}
```

When I run the test now, it does execute the original `SaveQuotes()`, but as a side-effect it also runs the original `DoSomething()` method too.

How can I run the original `SaveQuotes()` but the faked `DoSomething()`. TypeMock does this will the `.CallOriginal` option when setting up fakes, but I cannot see how to do the same in MS Fakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I got it now.

I had to change the `ShimBehaviors.InstanceBeahviour` property like so:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        var sutShim = new ShimPerson();

        sutShim.DoSomething = () => { Console.WriteLine("Called from test"); };

        sutShim.InstanceBehavior = ShimBehaviors.Fallthrough;

        sutShim.Instance.SaveQuotes();
    }
}
```

This tells Fakes to call the original `SaveQuotes()` method, whilst still using the faked `DoSomething()` method. I found this to be a good reference:

http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2012/05/10/shim-and-instancebehavior-fallthrough-to-isolate-part-of-the-sut/